# From developer to designer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend, web-frontend

Well, this is a really common and "wide" question. 
I'm a web developer and I have experience in solving server side problems.
How can I start to learn Front-End world?
I need to become as soon as possible a "Bootstrap-aware" developer!

Comment: This question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. It is too broad, primarily opinion based and looking for off site resources.

Comment: The bootstrap getting started page is as good as any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of reading over the [**Getting Started**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) section of the Bootstrap site, there are several tutorials that you could take advantage of.

> W3Schools - [Bootstrap 3 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)
>
> Code School - [Blasting Off with Bootstrap](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/blasting-off-with-bootstrap)
>
> Treehouse - [Bootstrap Library](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/q:bootstrap?SSAID=1016096)
>
> Lynda.com - [Up and Running with Bootstrap 3](http://www.lynda.com/Bootstrap-tutorials/Up-Running-Bootstrap-3/133339-2.html)
>
> Coder's Guide - [Bootstrap 3 Tutorial Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXVoqJEwqoQ)

Hope this helps your cause.